# Is there any way to Indentify the Time if it comes 12 Hour format without AM/PM?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting date from web service in 12 hour Format like this **@"2012-11-23 04:46:19.120"**. Is there any way to identify weather this time is AM or PM? Please guide me what should I do to get the correct result?

I am getting Dictionary in Response like this:

{

```
address = "22 W 46th St,\nNew York,New York,10036";
"business_name" = "Monster Sushi Midtown";
"con_res_id" = 5940;
"current_date" = "2012-11-23 04:46:19.120";
"deal_description" = "Enjoy Happy Hour with $3 Large Beers & $2 Regular Beers";
```

}

Comment: Is the `@` part of the data? Do you receive this `@` all the time or only ~50% of the time. Else I am afraid there is just no way.

Comment: "current_date" = "2012-11-23 04:46:19.120"; I am getting response like this

Comment: Your dictionary contains date, so what is the significance of AM/PM? 25Dec is always Christmas 10AM or PM doesnt matter, isn't it?

Comment: That is correct but i have to use this date for compassion with another date which contains "2012-11-23 03:00 PM" format like this so is there any way to compare the two different kind of date format?

Comment: discard the timestamp from both the dates and compare !!! But you need to save the date(without timestamp) in a string, a NSDate will always contain time with it.

Comment: Nope currently we dont have such mechanism, it is better if you ask server team to give proper output. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks iosRider for your question and providing some informations.

The answer is NO.

If your database is not storing the AM / PM, cocoa cant convert it into AM or PM.

Now what you can do is :

Discard the timestamp from both the dates, store it in NSString and compare !!!

Answer (score 1):

no, if the date format of the response is a 12 hours format and do not include the AM/PM value there is no way to infer it.